# How to render a list of static content with Vue named slot?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components, slot

I have trouble figuring out how to get the following to work:

My parent template

```
<comp>
  <a href="#" slot="links">link 1</a>
  <a href="#" slot="links">link 2</a>
</comp>
```

and my component `comp` template looks like the following:

```
<ul class="comp">
  <li class="comp-item"><slot name="links"></slot></li>
</ul>
```

currently all my anchors goes to that single `li` tag (which is expected)
but I would like to be able to produce multiple `li` for every named slot I inserted like the following:

```
<ul class="comp">
  <li class="comp-item"><a href="#" slot="links">link 1</a></li>
  <li class="comp-item"><a href="#" slot="links">link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to achieve what I need without using scoped slot? Because my content is pure HTML so I feel it is unnecessary to put static content inside prop in order to render them.

From what I have seen, most vue UI framework requires you to use another custom component for the list item, which I feel is over killed for the problem. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with a render function.

```
Vue.component("comp", {
  render(h){
    let links = this.$slots.links.map(l => h('li', {class: "comp-item"}, [l]))
    return h('ul', {class: 'comp'}, links)
  }
})
```

Here is a working example.

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component("comp", {
  render(h){
    let links = this.$slots.links.map(l => h('li', {class: "comp-item"}, [l]))
    return h('ul', {class: 'comp'}, links)
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <comp>
    <a href="#" slot="links">link 1</a>
    <a href="#" slot="links">link 2</a>
  </comp>
</div>
```

Or with the help of a small utility component for rendering vNodes you could do it like this with a template.

```js
Vue.component("vnode", {
  functional: true,
  render(h, context){
    return context.props.node
  }
})

Vue.component("comp", {
  template: `
    <ul class="comp">
      <li class="comp-item" v-for="link in $slots.links"><vnode :node="link" /></li>
    </ul>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <comp>
    <a href="#" slot="links">link 1</a>
    <a href="#" slot="links">link 2</a>
  </comp>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! the vnode solution looks very interesting and just be what I need, I didnt know about this technique!

Comment: You can also use scoped slots right?.. what would be the advantage of render function over scoped slot for this particular use case :-)

Comment: @VamsiKrishna The premise of the question is that the provided links are not in data, but "static" (hardcoded in the slot). So, no, I don't think a scoped slot does anything for you in this case.

Comment: @Bert ok got it you are right....but still updated my answer to use a static option instead of placing the links in data option

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots) instead of slots

Your `comp` component receives a prop `links`  which is an array of links(since static initialized as a [custom option](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-options)). Iterate over the `links` and pass `link` as data to the slot just like passing props to a component

```
   Vue.component("comp", {
  template: `
    <ul class="comp">
      <li class="comp-item" v-for="link in links">
          <slot v-bind="link"></slot>
      </li>
    </ul>
  `,
  props: ["links"]
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  // custom static option , accessed using vm.$options.links
  links: [
      {text: "link1"},
      {text: "link2"},
      {text: "lin3"}
  ]
})
```

In the parent where the `comp` component is used  make use of a  `<template>` element with a special attribute `slot-scope` , indicating that it is a template for a scoped slot.

The value of `slot-scope` will be used as the name of a temporary variable that holds the props object passed from the child:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <comp :links="$options.links">
      <template slot-scope="link">
          <a href="#">{{link.text}}</a>
      </template>
  </comp>
</div>
```

Here is the [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nxr171c/20/)

Comment: I found the two links outside of slot scope weren't getting rendered in the demo

Comment: @Stvyu oh...thery were added there by mistake.... as i commented to bert's answer, his answer would be more dynamic one. To learn more why you can check out:  https://adamwathan.me/renderless-components-in-vuejs/?utm_campaign=Revue%20newsletter&utm_medium=Newsletter&utm_source=Vue.js%20Developers

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to put your data in array, and render list with `v-for`

You can put all of them in the component, no slot:

```
<ul class="comp">
  <li class="comp-item"><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li class="comp-item"><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

or with slot:

```
<comp>
  <ul class="comp" slot="links">
    <li class="comp-item"><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li class="comp-item"><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</comp>
```

Comment: For the first solution, it wont suit my case as I may have different list item in different situations. For the second solution, my slotted HTML will need to know what the required styling classes for the component are, which isn't very modular in my opinion.