# Vue3 Manually Render Slot Content

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuejs-slots

I'm trying to parse out the contents of a slot and render the contents in multiple places. The idea is to create a wizard that allows each step to be contained in a single component. Something like this:

Wizard Component Definition:

```html
<ul>
    <li v-for="icon in icons">{{icon}}<li>
</ul>
<section>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="body in bodies">{{body}}</li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

Wizard Component Script

```js
import {ref} from "vue";

export default {
    setup(props, {slots}) {
        const icons = ref([]);
        const bodies = ref([]);

        for (let item of slots.default()) {
            // not sure if I need to call these, ex: item.children.icon()
            icons.value.push(item.children.icon);
            bodies.value.push(item.children.body);
        }
        
        return {icons, bodies};
    }
}
```

Wizard Component Usage:

```html
<wizard>
    <wizard-page>
        <template #icon>someIcon</template>
        <template #body>someBody</template>
    </wizard-page>
    <wizard-page>
        <template #icon>someIcon2</template>
        <template #body>someBody2</template>
    </wizard-page>
</wizard>
```

The obvious problem here is that everything is VNodes and doesn't just render nicely to the DOM.  I've tried using `render()` and `h()` but those don't *seem* to be what I'm looking for.  Also tried the v-html binding, but again, that isn't expecting a VNode.

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this, or if I'm missing something simple here, but I'm not seeing an easy way to split apart a slot and render the contents in different places.

Comment: Do you know how many wizard-page your wizard can accept? The slot name can be very dynamic in vue, so I am thinking your Wizard component can take one number prop called steps, and then you can assume the slots are named as page-0 to page-[steps]. Basically the slot name does not have to be statically known to either side, but you need an agreement between the slot provider and consumer on the format of the name. I've never tried a Wizard component but I have done similar things with layout manager controls such as golden layout.

Comment: @Xinchao The number of steps is variable but reasonably no more than 8 or 10 probably.  That is an interesting point about dynamic slot names though.  Maybe I could use `<wizard-icon-#>` and `<wizard-body-#>` , then use `Object.keys(slots)` to get the names of all slots, then group based on number, and finally render conditional slots with dynamic names based on the loop index.  That wouldn't be quite as clean as I was hoping but would probably get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

VUE 3

```
<component :is="body">
```

You can implement it in the following way

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="body in bodies" :key="uniquekey">
    <component :is="body" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

link to docs:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/component-basics.html#dynamic-components

Comment: I know it has been a long time since this question, however if anyone else is here like I was, this was the right answer. Maybe not described best. You can check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352525/can-you-render-vnodes-in-a-vue-template for a better explanation